# ZXing Barcode Writer Destructor

Tags: vb.net, qr-code, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am attempting to write a program with ZXing which continually scans keyboard input, converting the input into a QR code. This QR code is then read by using the BarcodeReader Class. The BarcodeReader keeps the resources for this file, even after the subroutine that contains the object has completed. This prevents me from being able to save a new QR Code which overwrites the existing QR Code because it is still in use! To solve this problem I attempted to invoke the destructor for the class, but there is none I can find. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.The code below is where the destructor should be called.

```
'Read any 2D Barcode, this will only ever be a QR code for this project
 Private Function read2D(location As String)
    Dim reader = New ZXing.BarcodeReader()
    Try
        Dim result = reader.Decode(Bitmap.FromFile(location))
        Return "Succesfully Read 2D Barcode:" + result.ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return "Error Reading 2D Barcode"
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the BarcodeReader who holds the lock.
You have to dispose the bitmap instance which you get from Bitmap.FromFile.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sahykhd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I invoked the destructor and then forced garbage collection. It worked perfectly!